# Two IN() Operators, One Column

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to select a row based on passing two IN() operators, but for the same column. Here's what I've attempted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `product_id`, `department` 
  FROM `products` 
 WHERE `department` IN ('Star Wars', 'Scarface', 'Winnie the Pooh') 
   AND `department` IN ('T-Shirts', 'Frisbees', 'Waffles')
```

The query returns no results.

The `products` table contains two important columns: `product_id` and `department`. This assigns the same product to multiple departments. For example, there is a Darth Vader t-shirt assigned to three different departments - Star Wars, T-Shirts and Waffles.

I am trying to make a form to allow a user to search for "Darth Vader" and to specify to only return results from the "Star Wars" and "T-Shirt" departments, while skipping over all other Darth Vader memorabilia.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `department` is a VARCHAR? How are you assigning one product to multiple departments? Is `product_id` not a primary key? Can we see some sample rows?

Comment: Does `department` currently contain a comma delimited list? If so a junction table with `productid`,`departmentid` would be the best way of structuring this.

Comment: Or do you mean you have more than one record for each product and you want to find products that both a Star Wars and a T-shirt record? But not any other records?

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE IN (...)` is basicaly the equivalent of `where x='a' or x='b' or x='c'...`. What you've done with your dual WHERE IN is saying "department must be both one of the first set AND part of the second set. Basically "1 is 2 is 3".

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the structure of your database is somewhat odd. You should have a `products` table and a `departments` table and one last table `product_to_deptt` that would connect them.

That way, doing what you want to do, would be very easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should include all relevant Departments in a single `IN` statements unless you are deliberately trying to `SELECT` only their overlapping values. If you must use the syntax like you have above, then consider using `OR`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM `products`   
 WHERE `department` IN ('Star Wars', 'T-Shirts')
   AND whatever_it_is = 'Darth Vader';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeking products where the department is IN one list AND IN a second list. Assuming that the two department lists are mutually exclusive, an inner self join can be used for the AND condition:

```
select p1.product_id
    from products p1
        inner join products p2
            on p1.product_id = p2.product_id
                and p2.department in ('T-Shirts', 'Frisbees', 'Waffles')
    where p1.department in ('Star Wars', 'Scarface', 'Winnie the Pooh')
```